# Unable to link react-native with rn-fetch-blob

Tags: react-native

I want to display a pdf in my react-native app. I used documentation from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf. I installed rn-fetch-blob and react-native-pdf. i have linked react-native-pdf .
but when i ran command "react-native link rn-fetch-blob" it didn't get linked.
and i got the following message in command prompt:

```
rn-fetch-blob will not automatically add Android permissions after 0.9.4 
please run the following command if you want to add default permissions :

    RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true react-native link
```

I tried this command and i got:
    "'RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I am using this version: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.8

I also tried to set it manually with the reference https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package

I was to set it in 3 files according to the last reference i provided -

I used first: "node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/android/build.gradle" (which is "android/app/build.gradle" in documentation )

I used second:  "node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/android/src/main/java/com/RNFetchBlob/RNFetchBlob.java" (which is "MainApplication.java" in documentation )

third file was "android/settings.gradle" which i didn't find in "node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/android/"

so i bacame unable to set it manually.

May be I am using wrong file paths to set it manually. If any one have any idea about it or any suggestions for me to solve it in a better way. please help me out.
Or if any other way to solve "displaying a pdf in react-native" please provide me that also.

Comment: What rn fetch blob version did you install? latest one? Another thing, the guide you linked is from a deprecated version of rn fetch blob

Answer (score 2):

linking problem is solved after setting it manually and than by using command `set RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true` in command prompt.

But now still getting an error after using in code `import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';` . the error is shown below.[image: null is not an object(evaluating 'RNFetchBlob.DocumentDir')]

anyone having idea about it. or any other way to display a pdf in react-native, kindly let me know.

Comment: Probably not very useful, but I had this error too and it went away after rebuilding the app. Thank you for the `set` command. It worked, but unfortunately using `RNFetchBlob` instead of `RNFS` didn't resolve my cached image erroneously showing up in my app after taking a picture.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this command "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.13",install this version is worked for me,if you install another one your app was crashed/stoped.

Comment: i installed the same. then i linked it with command "react-native link rn-fetch-blob" . It shown me "'Add Android permissions => false
rn-fetch-blob will not automatically add Android permissions after 0.9.4 please run the following command if you want to add default permissions :

        RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true react-native link"    then i ran "RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true react-native link" . it shown me error "'RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."